# Microsoft Solver Foundation gives wrong answer for a simple ILP

Tags: c#, solver, constraint-programming, ms-solver-foundation, linear-optimization

I want to solve a binary Linear Problem in C# using Microsoft Solver Foundation. I don't know why I get wrong answer. The Objective Value should be 41.1 but I get 213. The value of 5 variables should be 1 and the other ones should be 0. But I get many many variables with wrong values.

The sum of each row of the matrix should be <= 1. That are my constraints, and as you see in *Constraint_arr* I get the right constraints.

Thanks for any help.

[image][image]

[image]

Define decision variables:

```
        SolverContext context = SolverContext.GetContext();
        Model model = context.CreateModel();
        Decision[,] x = new Decision[name_column.Length, 7];

        for (int i = 0; i < name_column.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            {
                x[i, j] = new Decision(Domain.IntegerRange(0,1), "x" + i + j);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < name_column.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            {
                model.AddDecisions(x[i, j]);
            }
        }
```

Create Constraint and add it to model:

```
Term[] Constraint_arr = new Term[name_column.Length];
        Term tempC;
        int jj;
        for (int i = 0; i < name_column.Length; i++)
        {
            tempC = 0;
            for (jj= 0; jj < 7; jj++)
            {
                if(vars_Matrix[i,jj] == 1)
                {
                    tempC += x[i,jj];
                }
            }
            Constraint_arr[i] = tempC;
            model.AddConstraints("constraint" + i, Constraint_arr[i] <= 1);
        }
```

Create Objective Function:

```
        Term objective_Func = 0;
        Term tempZ;
        for (int i = 0; i < name_column.Length; i++)
        {
            tempZ = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            {
                tempZ += x[i, j] * ratio[i];
            }
            objective_Func+= tempZ;
        }

        model.AddGoal("Goal", GoalKind.Maximize, objective_Func);
```

print the answer:

```
        Solution solution = context.Solve(new SimplexDirective());

        Report report = solution.GetReport();

        for (int i = 0; i < name_column.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(x[i, j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        
        Console.Write("{0}", report);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I don't see any obvious mistake. Rather than using this discontinued solver, you might be better off by using [MiniZinc](https://www.minizinc.org/), [Z3Py](https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/guide-examples.htm), [gplk](https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/) or [CPLEX](https://www.ibm.com/analytics/cplex-optimizer).

Comment: @AxelKemper Thank you for your response! I'll try some new solver.

Answer (score 2):

The following MiniZinc model arrives at 14 as maximum value for the objective:

```
set of int: rows = 1..5;
set of int: cols = 1..7;
array[rows, cols] of 0..1: vars_Matrix = [|0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1
                                          |0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1
                                          |0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0
                                          |0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1
                                          |0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0|];
                                          
array[cols] of var 0..1: c;
var int: obj;

%  constraint 
%      obj = sum(i in rows)(
%              sum(j in cols) (
%                c[i] * vars_Matrix[i, j]
%              )
%            );

constraint
  obj = sum([ sum([ c[i] * vars_Matrix[i, j] | j in cols ]) | i in rows ]);    

solve maximize(obj);
```

Output

```
c = array1d(1..7, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]);
obj = 14;
```

---

The same result is obtained from the following Z3py model:

```py
    from z3 import *
    
    s = Optimize()
    
    Rows = range(5);
    Cols = range(7);
    vars_Matrix = [[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                   [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
                   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
                                              
    c = [Int("c" + str(i+1)) for i in Rows]
    obj = Int("obj")
    
    for i in Rows:
        s.add(c[i] >= 0, c[i] <= 1)
    
    s.add(obj == Sum( [ Sum( [ c[i] * vars_Matrix[i][j] for j in Cols ] ) for i in Rows ] ))
    
    s.maximize(obj)
    
    if sat == s.check():
        print(s.model())
    else:
        print("No solution. Sorry!")
```